# Windows: how can an application forced to always connect thought a proxy?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy

We would like to use the `Tencent QQ` instant messaging client on some Windows laptops in the company. We a have to record the chat logs and because of this the QQ client should always connect thought a WFilter Enterprise proxy server.

The QQ client can be configured to use a `HTTP or SOCK5 proxy`, but it considers the proxy as an additional way to connect and not as the only one. If the proxy connection fails the QQ client silently connects directly and we can't capture the logs.

I found `Proxifier`, but it is a user space application which can't seem to run as a background service. User can simply close it or change the configuration.

Using a `transparent proxy` on the LAN is not possible because these laptops are often outside the office network. We don't have the  need to tunnel everything thought the proxy.

I'm looking for a way to force the QQ client application running on Windows to always go though the proxy server.

Do you have any suggestions on this?

Comment: So, network wide solution are impossible for you (laptops are outside the office). That leaves you with user space programs which run as administrator so users can not close them. If users have admin rights - that probably leaves you with nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started to try all [proxifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_proxifiers) applications and found that [ProxyCap](http://www.proxycap.com/) seems to fit my requirements the best.

- It installs a service to allow proxying other services and background processes.
- The configuration is done on the system level.
- It can be setup to download the configuration rule-set from a central server.

Unfortunately, the tray icon application allows to enable/disable ProxyCap, but removing it from the startup may be enough to stop the users from accidentally disabling it.

It support 32 and 64 bit Windows systems up to Win8 and has a Mac version, too.